# swift - URL send data to server

Tags: swift, urlsession

So I am needing to send a simple query to the server from swift.

I thought the following would work however I am getting

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'
```

Wondering if anyone knows why>?

```
let locationurl = URL(string: "https://api.drn1.com.au:9000/listener?uuid=\(uuid ?? "")&lat=\(location.latitude)&long=\(location.longitude)")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: locationurl) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
             // Handle Error
             return
         }
         guard let response = response else {
             // Handle Empty Response
             return
         }
         guard let data = data else {
             // Handle Empty Data
             return
         }
         // Handle Decode Data into Model
    }
```

Comment: That code compiles without any issues.

Comment: Please, update the provided code with missing parts. Issue is somewhere else.

Comment: the issue was the resume() part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let url = "Write here the URL"
     let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
     request.url = URL(string: String(format: "%@", url))
     request.httpMethod = "POST"

     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in


       guard error == nil else {

          print("error calling POST on HitServices is\(String(describing: error))")

          return
       }

       guard let responseData = data else {
          print("Error: did not receive data")
          return
       }

    }
    task.resume()
```